# Can I create an Apex.Stack for any type?

Tags: apex

Can I create an `Apex.Stack` for any type?

If I will do:

```
Apex.Stack stackForIds = new Apex.Stack();
```

Then I am able to put id values in such a stack:

```
stackForIds.push(anId);
```

Here is how I tried to put an `SObject` into my stack:

```
Apex.Stack<SObject> stackForSObjects= new Apex.Stack<SObject>();
stackForSObjects.push(new SObject(Id = anId));
```

And it did not work out. I am getting an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol `Apex.Stack<SObject>`

[image]

There seems to be no documentation on the `Apex.Stack`, so I would be grateful for it. Otherwise I am asking for help to figure out whether or not `Apex.Stack` is able to work with an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such class in the platform's API, look in your own code base for a class called `Apex` that has an inner class called `Stack`.

If you want to support other types, you will have to add additional methods for those and generalize the implementation. Other languages include better mechanisms for this situation - see e.g. Java's [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Though as this `Apex.Stack` code probably does very little, changing the method signatures and implementation to use `Object` rather than `Id` would probably be the best way to go as then all types would be supported. But casts would be needed when values are popped.

**PS**

Correction from sfdcfox:

> There is a hidden class called Apex.Stack, and a related exception,
>   Apex.StackEmptyException. It has a few methods available in it. It was
>   never documented because of some "edge cases" where it would
>   inexplicably break as well as a general lack of performance. I wasn't
>   given any more than that, but this information came directly from
>   someone with access to the source code for it, so it is at least
>   accurate.

Comment: Oh. That explains why I was not able to find the documentation on `Apex.Stack`.

Comment: @iloveseven Yeah I'm a bit surprised you can even create a class called `Apex` as it makes you think it is a platform feature.

Comment: Apex is not a recognised keyword, so I belive it should not cause  compilation error. Which makes sense.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You mean a reserved word ?

Comment: I think the @sfdcfox answer is correct. I am able to push such code (Apex.Stack ss = new Apex.Stack()) in my Dev org. i.e. Such class is available in SF but due to some known limitation not documented.

Comment: @KeithC There is a hidden class called Apex.Stack, and a related exception, Apex.StackEmptyException. It has a few methods available in it. It was never documented because of some "edge cases" where it would inexplicably break as well as a general lack of performance. I wasn't given any more than that, but this information came directly from someone with access to the source code for it, so it is at least accurate.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've added your comment to the answer, and +1 from me for your answer; makes sense for the OP to accept yours instead though.

Answer (score 8):

The Apex.Stack class has known limitations and bugs, which is why it was never formally released in the documentation. Do not use it if you care about the stability of your code.